# Liberar acesso a pastas no .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Antes de tudo quero dizer que já pesquisei aqui no stack e nenhum dos exemplos me ajudou. Porem se achar que está duplicada favor indicar o o link da solução.

Tenho configurado em uma aplicação o .htaccess para o ZEND 1.12

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Então ao acessar um link de uma imagem ele da erro dizendo que o controller é invalido. Pois a sequencia da url é /controller/action/param/123

Ex:

```
http://localhost:85/img/catalog/paisagem.jpg4
```

Sei que isso se deve ao fato de não estar liberado para acesso a pasta IMG/CATALOG no .htaccess tentei fazer alguns exemplos e nenhum funcionou, um que tentei funcionou, mostrou a imagem mas o zend nao ficou configurado para acessar normalmente ai tive que voltar e colocar o mesmo codigo acima para o site funcionar novamente.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Acredita que eu estava trabalhando com um framework e tive esse mesmo problema a 2 horas, rs

Se eu entedi o que você perguntou, para que a pasta informada não seja afetada pelo `mod_rewrite` você deve adicionar um novo `.htaccess` dentro da pasta `img` por exemplo, como deve ser o conteudo do `.htaccess`:

```apacheconf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Exemplo de estrutura de pasta:

```
.
├── img
|   ├── .htaccess (arquivo para liberar acesso desta pasta)
|   └── catalog
|       └── paisagem.jpg4
├── .htaccess (arquivo usado pelo zend)
└── index.php
```

Comment: VLWWWWW!!!! certinho!! e para proteger que nao seja listado todas as imagens adicionei um index.html em branco. Quero que seja visto somente a imagem que eu colocar no link. Enfim resolveu aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: @rafaelphp A tática do index.html é muito boa mesmo.